# woocommerce virtual generated PDF

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce

I want to sell generated PDF on my WordPress/woo commerce site:
Each product has to be a generated PDF containing unique QR code.

Typically, the user will buy this product on the website and will receive by email later this generated PDF (this pdf is not the invoice!) containing this unique QRCode.

How can I create virtual products that are automatically generated and unique?
(to later send by email).

[edit]

I am really asking which PHP files should I modify to be able to do so?

cheers

Comment: thanks for the link, but my question is not how to generate a PDF in PHP, but how to sell generated PDF for each customer on my woocommerce site?

Comment: I don't think that StackOverflow is the place to ask such a question. If the question is: I am using iText to add a unique QR code to an already existing PDF, this is my code and the problem is X, then you have a StackOverflow question. If your question is "how to sell a PDF on a web site", then you don't have a StackOverflow question. I vote to close.

Comment: well ... I am really asking the technical part : which php classes should I touch and/or which hooks should I trigger to be able to do this?

Comment: Would you be generating this pdf and sending it? I would just make a virtual product in woocommerce for that.

Comment: yes exactly. but when is there any triggered hook (or anything happening) for me to detect when the purchased has been completed and the system can generates the PDF and send it by email?

Comment: The `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook fires when the payment is completed... so it seems like a good place to generate your PDFs and email them.